# Smarty Error on Wamp server

Tags: php, wamp, smarty

I got an error when installing php openCRM software myITCRM.`Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Call of unknown method 'load_filter'. <-- thrown in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\Smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 858`.

Comment: We would need to see code to be helpful. Are you calling that method, or is it failing internally?

Answer (score 1):

`load_filter()` was used in Smarty 2.0, but became `loadFilter()` in Smarty 3.0. My guess is that your application's Smarty libraries have been upgraded, but this piece of code hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

myITCRM will not work in php 5.5 .that's why i am getting this error